# failed deployment of google cloud function because of failed container health check

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a Python google cloud function. When I try to deploy it first will go through the function build. that is successful. BUT after that the deployment fails with this error message

Could not create or update Cloud Run service move-docai-to-bigquery, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'move-docai-to-bigquery-00012-xuv' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information

It seems to have something to do with a port setting in a container instance but I do not know how to fix it. Here is my python code.. can anybody help ?

````
import uuid

import pytest
from samples.snippets import entities_to_bigquery_sample

from google.cloud import bigquery

location = "us"
project_id = os.environ["finance-ap-397417"]
gcs_bucket_name = "hd-dociaoutput"
gcs_input_uri = "gs://hd-dociaoutput/27358output.json"
dataset_name = f"invoicedocai"
table_name = f"invoices"


def MOVE_DOCAI_TO_BIGQUERY (capsys: pytest.CaptureFixture) -> None:
    client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)
    dataset = bigquery.Dataset(f"{project_id}.{dataset_name}")
    dataset.location = "US"
    dataset = client.create_dataset(dataset, timeout=30, exists_ok=True)

    entities_to_bigquery_sample.entities_to_bigquery_sample(
        gcs_bucket_name=gcs_bucket_name,
        gcs_prefix=gcs_input_uri,
        dataset_name=dataset_name,
        table_name=table_name,
        project_id=project_id,
    )
    out, _ = capsys.readouterr()

    assert "Document entities loaded into BigQuery" in out
    assert "Job ID:" in out
    assert (
        f"Table: /projects/{project_id}/datasets/{dataset_name}/tables/{table_name}"
        in out
    )```
I read container related documentation but do not understand how to proceed
````